# Flex for mobile: images are better off in assets folder or database

Tags: database, image, flex4

I'm building a simple Flex App for mobile to test things out.
Is it ok to store some images in an SQLite database or is it better to have them in the filesystem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If images are bundled with the app, I would use filesystem (or embed them in the Flex App which is basically the same thing).

If images are saved based on user input, SQLite might be the better solution.

Storing images in a database is usually not ideal.  But allowing users to write to the filesystem isn't ideal, either.  So you might have to pick the lesser of 2 evils.

Comment: Thank you, Teddy. Good insight.